# Close event in Java FX when close button is pressed

Tags: javafx-8

Is there any event handler present in Java FX, if i close a window directly bt pressing [X] button on Top right side.
Which events gets fire in this case ?
Nothing is working so far , neither setOnHiding not setOnCloseRequest()

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

### *Try this one*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Text text = new Text("!");
        text.setFont(new Font(40));
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().add(text);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box,300, 250);
        scene.setFill(null);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
          public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
              System.out.println("Stage is closing");
          }
      });        
        stage.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

## Source [Stage close event : Stage « JavaFX « Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Stagecloseevent.htm)

Comment: Well i have written stage.setOnCloseRequest(...) in stop method (overridden method). but it also didnt work. I try to debug but the control is not even reaching in stop method.

Comment: Actually my scenario is, I have to open 2 fxml at the same time. Suppose screen A and Screen B. Screen A is made "APPLICATION_MODAL".
what I want is - when i close screen A (by pressing [X] red button of windows),  Screen B should also gets closed.

Comment: public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
........
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        showSplashScreen();
        showLoginScreen();
    }

@override
    public void stop(){
        primaryStage.close();
    }

Comment: @user5122617 Don't put unformatted code in the comments - it is completely unreadable. Edit your question to include the code.

Comment: In Java 8+ version you can write
--- stage.setOnCloseRequest(we -> System.out.println("Stage is closing")); ---
rather code between  stage.show(); and  stage.close(); lines.