# JAVAFX Stage : Default button selection and alignment with text padding

Tags: javafx, vbox

I am new to Javafx and trying to implement a Warning/Confirmation Dialog box for the User.

I am able to get the dialog box, but unable to align it as per requirement.

Below is how my dialog box looks currently:
[image]

Now, I need to make two changes,

1. I want to have buttons side by side, with yes first and no after that. But No should be selected by default. So that on closing No is sent as response.
2. I want to have some space between the text and the buttons. Also is it possible to get text in two lines if the text size increases?

Below is my current code:

```
public static boolean display(String title, String message){
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setTitle("Confirmation");
        window.setMinWidth(540);
        window.setMinHeight(250);
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText(message);

        Button yesButton = new Button("Yes");
        Button noButton = new Button("no");

        yesButton.setOnAction(e->{
            answer = true;
            window.close();
        });

        noButton.setOnAction(e->{
            answer = false;
            window.close();
        });
        
        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label,noButton,yesButton);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.showAndWait();
        return answer;
    }
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: work through a tutorial on layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to have buttons side by side, with yes first and no after that

Put the buttons into a HBox

> No should be selected by default. So that on closing No is sent as response.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371117/close-event-in-java-fx-when-close-button-is-pressed) for a similar question

> I want to have some space between the text and the buttons.

Add some margin to the top of the HBox you will put your Buttons into

```
HBox h = //...
HBox.setMargin(h, new Insets(20, 0, 0, 0));
```

> Also is it possible to get text in two lines if the text size increases?

```
label.setWrapText(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Button` class does not support the `.setSelected` method, so we have to use the `ToggleButton` class:

```
    ToggleButton yesToggleButton = new ToggleButton("Yes");

    ToggleButton noToggleButton = new ToggleButton("No");

    noToggleButton.setSelected(true);
```

As you can also see, the word `Toggle` occurs in the `ToggleButton` class, which means that the button can either be selected or not.

---

Now we have to assign the `objects` of the class `ToggleButton` to a `ToggleGroup` object, because the `objects` of the class `ToggleButton` can be managed by the class `ToggleGroup`:

```
ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

yesToggleButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

noToggleButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
```

---

To create a distance from the buttons, we must now specify the coordinates for the `abscissa axis` and for the `ordinate axis`:

```
    yesToggleButton.setTranslateX(-100); // abscissa axis
    yesToggleButton.setTranslateY(25);  // ordinate axis

    noToggleButton.setTranslateX(100); // abscissa axis
    noToggleButton.setTranslateY(25); // ordinate axis
```

---

If the font size increases and the font is no longer readable, it can be displayed on another line using the `.setWrapText` method:

```
messageType.setFont(Font.font(20)); // sets the font size

messageType.setWrapText(true);
```

---

You have used the `VBox` class, which aligns `objects` vertically. Since you want the `objects` to be horizontal, you can use `HBox`, or to align the `objects` in any direction, I would recommend `StackPane`:

```
StackPane root = new StackPane();
```

---

I would recommend this method to you to set the scene:

```
Stage confirmationWindow = new Stage();

confirmationWindow.setScene(new Scene(root, 540, 323));
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikail for you help. This is really very helpful.